# Which object properties are not allowed in a JS object in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

A few months ago I discovered through great pain that you cannot do this in IE:

```
{class:'bacon'}
```

Because "class" is a reserved word. Today I discovered that `export` is also a reserved word in IE. As I understand it, reserved or not, they *should* be valid within this context. I'm having trouble finding any documentation on this though.

What keywords are invalid to use as unquoted property names in Internet Explorer (or other browsers if they too impose restrictions)?

Comment: Here's a list of JavaScript reserved words.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: @RocketHazmat Damn, beat me by 2 seconds

Comment: @MikeRobinson: I'm a ninja ^_^

Comment: Not IE specific. "SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word" when I type that into google chrome console as well.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: And none of those are allowed as property names?

Comment: @Mark have you tried `{"class": "bacon"}`?  You can use reserved words as property names all you want, so long as you do it via string constants instead of identifiers.

Comment: @Mark: They are!  You just need to quote them.  `{'class':'bacon'}` :-P

Comment: @Pointy: Read the last sentence carefully :-) I wrote "unquoted" for good reason.

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's really curious. I get the same error when I run it in the console, but it works within a `<script>` tag. Edit: What Rocket said.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Try `a={class:'bacon'}` in Chrome's console.

Comment: @Mark: It's because the console was reading the `{}` as a ["block"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), not as an object.

Comment: @Mark: Nothing on that list can be used as an "unquoted property name".  But with quotes, anything is possible! :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat: That's a good enough answer for me. You're welcome to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use quotes around your property names, it works fine!

```
{'class':'bacon'}
```

If you are asking about unquotes property names, here's a list of JavaScript reserved words:

```
break
case
catch
continue
debugger
default
delete
do
else
finally
for
function
if
in
instanceof
new
return
switch
this
throw
try
typeof
var
void
while
with

class
enum
export
extends
import
super
```

The following are only reserved words when in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode):

```
implements
interface
let
package
private
protected
public
static
yield
```

<sub>Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words</sub>

None of these can be used as an unquoted property name in IE <= 8.

Comment: "None of these can be used as an unquoted property name." -- *in Internet Explorer*. They *are* allowed as per the official spec, aren't they?

Comment: @Mark: To be safe, I'd quote them in all browsers.  IE9+, and Chrome don't seem to care.  I didn't check what the spec said.

Comment: `var a= {super: 123,class:'bacon'}` works in IE 9 and above too. It's IE 8 and below that have the problem.

Comment: @Mark: The spec says reserved words are only an issue in identifier names (like you can't do `var class = 'bacon';` in any browser).  Seems objects don't have that issue.  IE8 and below just don't follow the spec, I guess.  Spec link: http://es5.github.io/#x7.6

Comment: Yeah.. I should get into the habit of just quoting everything. I generally don't like extraneous things :p All these [silly libraries](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) never seem to promote quoting your keys.

Comment: @Mark: If you make sure to never use any of these words, you can keep them unquoted :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Well...hence the question :-)